# Prevent popen from showing a command's output

Tags: c++, popen

I'm using the following C++ function to execute simple commands and get their output to a std::string:

```
std::string runcmd(std::string cmd)
{
    std::stringstream output;

    FILE *stream = popen(cmd.c_str(), "r");
    char buffer[512];

    if( !stream )
    {
        return "popen error";
    }

    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stream) != NULL)
    {
        output << buffer;
    }

    pclose(stream);
    return output.str();
}
```

But the behaviour is not the same for every command I've tried. For example, if I call "ls -l ~" everything works OK, but if I call "crontab -l", the output is shown in the console. How can I prevent this behaviour?

Comment: I can't repeat your error. Your code works the same for both commands when I run it. Perhaps the error is elsewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. My program is just a main containing the following lines: runcmd("ls -l ~"); runcmd("crontab -l");

Comment: Is the `crontab` command printing an error message? That would appear on the console unless you redirect the error stream.

Comment: It just informing "no crontab for user -----". Should I redirect it then?

Comment: If you want the error output then you will have to redirect it using `2>&1` at the end of your command. If you want to be able to read both the output and the error output separately then I think you'll have to use `fork()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`popen` catches `stdout`, not `stderr`. It only creates one pipe for output, so @Galik's comment is correct. Use `2>&1` to redirect stderr(2) to stdout(1), or `fork` the process and manually deal with all three streams.